# div overflow x scroll not working

Tags: html, css

I want to create div with overflow effect. here is my code

```
<div style="width:100%;clear:both;overflow-x:auto">
   <div style="width:50%; float:left; background:#ccc;height:200px"></div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left; background:#333;height:200px"></div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left; background:#cc90fc;height:200px"></div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left; background:#000;height:200px"></div>
</div>
```

i want these div don't come below while overflow, the container div will have a scroll bar, any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `whitespace:nowrap` to parent container, and `display:inline-block` to children elements

When **whitespace:nowrap** is given, the content inside doesn't go to the next line.

```html
<div style="width:100%;overflow-x:auto;white-space: nowrap; font-size:0">
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block;  background:#ccc;height:200px; font-size:initial"></div>
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block;  background:#333;height:200px; font-size:initial"></div>
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block;  background:#cc90fc;height:200px; font-size:initial"></div>
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block;  background:#000;height:200px; font-size:initial"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid gap between `display:inline-block` element you should use `font-size:0;` in container elements. Also add `vertical-align` to keep the child element in same line. See below:

```html
<div style="width:100%;overflow-x:auto; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 0;">
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; background:#ccc; height:200px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top;">afadsf afdafdsaf</div>
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; background:#333; height:200px; font-size: 12px;  vertical-align: top;"></div>
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; background:#cc90fc; height:200px; font-size: 12px;  vertical-align: top;"></div>
  <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; background:#000; height:200px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can still see the gap in between, i guess it's not practical to be a fixed size.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I updated my answer. font-size: 0 is key issue to remove white space in between the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you don't want the div to show when it overflows vertically (up and down) instead of horizontally (left to right) you should be using the overflow-y style instead of the overflow-x style.

Change `style="width:100%;clear:both;overflow-x:auto` to `style="width:100%;clear:both;overflow-y:auto` in your style attribute.

Comment: That being said, you also need to define the height of the parent div.  (I'm assuming there isn't an element wrapping it that defines the size)